# How to replace a word in every CFG file of a folder with the CFG file name?

Tags: file, batch-file, replace

I would like to know if there is a possibility with batch or script to change a word being always the same word in several *.cfg files by replacing it with the name of the CFG file?

For example in these *.cfg files

```
aaaaaa.cfg
bbbbbb.cfg
cccccc.cfg
...
```

I have always the word `kof98` on line 4 in each CFG file. I would like to replace the word `kof98` by `aaaaaa` without extension like the file name for the first CFG file. And make the same for the second CFG file by replacing `kof98` with `bbbbbb`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy to achieve task with using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript.

```
@echo off
if not exist "*.cfg" goto :EOF
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF

for %%I in (*.cfg) do call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "kof98" "%%~nI" /F "%%I" /O -
```

The batch file first checks if there is any *.cfg file in current directory and immediately exits if this condition is not true, see [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

The batch file **JREPL.BAT** must be stored in same directory as the batch file with the code above. For that reason the batch file checks next if **JREPL.BAT** really exists in directory of the batch file and exits if this condition is not true.

The command **FOR** searches in current directory for non hidden files matching the wildcard pattern `*.cfg` and calls for each found CFG file the batch file **JREPL.BAT** to case-sensitive replace any occurrence of `kof98` by the name of the CFG file without file extension.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 being the batch file itself.
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`